# How to design aluminum alloy melting furnace with nichrome coil heater of 800 watt 26 swg coil?

Tags: current-measurement

I have 800 watt 26 SWG of length 9 meter nichrome wire and 220 volt AC supply.  I want to heat nichrome coil up to 850C degree for aluminum alloy melting funace.

How much current will I need?

Will this work?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is simply no way to answer your question. You have failed to provide the most important bit of information - how good is the insulation of your proposed furnace?

If it's a perfect insulator, even one watt of power will do the job (although it will take a long time to do it).

However, that is not a likely way to operate.

Have you tried the [Wikipedia article on Nichrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nichrome)? I thought not.

Let's take your starting point. 26 ga NiCr-A has a nominal resistance of 2.5 ohms per foot, so at room temperature your spool of wire will have a resistance of about 74 ohms. If you were foolish enough to apply 220 volts to it, and the resistance did not change, you'd get about 1800 watt. The resistance would change, though, and probably by a factor of 3 or 4. So figure on something like 500 watts.

Is this enough? As I say, there is no way of knowing. I suggest you get some blocks of firebrick and actually make an oven. Then wind a coil out of your wire, making sure you include a means of keeping the individual layers from touching, and get a thermocouple and thermometer on eBay, and then do some experimenting.

Comment: One of the properties of nichrome that makes it a good choice for power resistors is that it doesn't change resistance by that much over the temperature range, and even getting it to red heat it'll only increase a few percent, so the dissipation doesn't fall much - the temperature it'll reach is mostly a balance between the loss by conduction/radiation and the power input, so some control is likely needed on a heater that produces enough heat to melt aluminum in a reasonable time to prevent it getting excessively hot if left powered.

Answer (score 0):

Best bet is to put in a temperature sensor and use feedback to regulate the current and therefore the temperature. Make sure the output is also fused and isolated. An ACDC converter to a voltage below 60V would be best to start, as 60V and under is typically considered safe.